# Can PrintWriter be used with sudo permissions?

Tags: java, authentication, sudo, printwriter

I'm trying to automate the process of creating virtual hosts in Linux. I need to create a file in /etc/apache2/sites-available and write in the /etc/hosts file. I'm trying to do that with the PrintWriter but don't know how to get the permission. The program is just for personal use but I still wouldn't want to safe my user password in the source code. Is there a way to request authentication and then run it as a sudo user?

Code so far:

public class NewProjectController {

```
static String path = "/etc/apache2/sites-available/test";

public static void createVirtualHost(String vhost) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(path, "UTF-8");
    writer.println("The first line");
    writer.println("The second line");
    writer.close();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Of course It can be used with sudo permission.
You just have to run it with `sudo java MainClassName`.